# How do I remove the hover effect on the buttons on my site?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

The buttons on my site look great except for when you hover them. When the are hovered over the font turns black and the button turns a light orange only halfway up. The top of the button remains the same. I would like css control over the attributes controlling hover effects but I do not see what is controlling them in the first pace.

```
      .btn {
         background-color: #f45F25;
         background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f47825, #f45F25);
         border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) #f47825;
         }
```

The web site is http://clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/ and the button is located at the top right in the Search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to remove the following CSS rules (that affect `.btn:hover`, the hover effect) in `insta-common.css`:

```
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position: 0 -15px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position .1s linear;
    transition: background-position .1s linear;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #005580;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: I added the code and adjusted the background position to cover the entire button when hovered. The problem now is that the button turn white when hovered and I can not seem to adjust the hover color.

Comment: .btn:hover, .btn:focus {
             color: #333;
             text-decoration: none;
             background-position: 0 -30px;
             -webkit-transition: background-position .1s linear;
             -moz-transition: background-position .1s linear;
             -o-transition: background-position .1s linear;
             transition: background-position .1s linear;
          }
          a:hover, a:focus {
             color: #005580;
             text-decoration: underline;
          }